# Capture initial copy of Propel objects in doSelect

Tags: php, select, propel

I am using Propel 1.6 and have a need to version all tables in a particular database. I have a number of tables, each having a versionable table defined in the schema (so table 'role' has a table 'role_versionable' as its versioning counterpart). When saving a record in 'role' I would like to copy the existing record to role_versionable before doing the save.

This is in itself trivial to do: I've set the baseClass for the whole schema to a custom class (which extends BaseObject) and all my generated row model classes extend this class. In my custom save routine I am doing a fresh select and then saving that to the versionable table. However I should be able to intercept doSelect[One] in all row classes, but I don't want to have to generate child objects for every table in the model.

I am therefore wondering if there is a way I can hook into a postSelect or get called automatically after every doSelect, to grab the initial state of the object after it is selected? This will then save me the extra select when I come to version the row.

(Detail: I am doing this in a custom way as I need to add extra metadata to the version table, which I don't believe the archive_behaviour supports.)

Comment: One approach I could take is to generate child classes for each of my peers (the system is a db application so I would have to do that programmatically on behalf of the user, but that is quite achievable). This would give me the opportunity to hook into each doSelect, but tbh it feels a little bit inelegant. So... any ideas? :-)

Comment: I may bounce this message on the Propel mailing list. But it won't be substantial effort to take the approach in my first comment - generate child classes. Not the most elegant of approaches, but sure to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to use a hook before or after a call to `doSelect`. Your best chance is to override this method in your own class and to add a hook by yourself. I'll probably write my own Peer builder to do that.

William

Comment: Ah, a custom peer builder - good idea. Since my application is for user-initiated database generation, I was thinking of using regex search and replace on all row classes as part of my custom build process; however, your suggestion is more elegant! I will make a note to try this in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your work on Propel, by the way - much appreciated.